# Convert XML structure to DataFrame using BeautifulSoup - python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a below XML structure without pretty print.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><animals><tiger>10</tiger><lion>20</lion><fox>30</fox></animals></root>
```

This is my code to convert XML structure to Pandas df.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
file = open("testing.xml","r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file.read(),'xml')
animals = soup.find_all('animals')
animal_list = []
for animal in animals:
   animal_list.append(animal.get_text())
animals_df = pd.DataFrame({'animals': animal_list})
animals_df
```

But my code does not produce correct result.

```
Actual result
   animals
0   102030

Expected result
   animals
0   10
1   20
2   30
```

Could anyone please help me to get the expected result?

Answer (score -1):

`find_all` returns a list. Since there's only one `animals` node, you should either use `animals = soup.find('animals')`, `animals = soup.find_all('animals')[0]` or `for animal in animals[0]:`

```
animals = soup.find('animals')
animal_list = []
for animal in animals:
    animal_list.append(animal.get_text())
print(pd.DataFrame({'animals': animal_list}))
#   animals
# 0      10
# 1      20
# 2      30
```

Comment: In case of multiple tags, say if my XML structure has <animals>...</animals> <reptiles>...</reptiles>, how it should work?

Comment: @WalkerRickies with a list of required nodes and another `for` loop (or a regex, `soup.find_all(re.compile(r'(animals|reptiles)'))`.